# glGetTexImage returns 0s with FBO

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

After learning that I have to use a [FBO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874510/how-can-i-read-float-data-with-glreadpixels) to read floating point data from shader, I have tried this but with no luck:

```
glGenTextures( 1, &renderTex );   
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, size, size, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, NULL );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );

glGenFramebuffers( 1, &fbo );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo );

glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &depth );
glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth );

glRenderbufferStorage( GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, size, size );
glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0 );

glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex, 0 );
glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth );

if ( !FBOStatusOK() ) return;

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glBindFramebuffer( GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER , m_FBO );
glClampColor( GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR, GL_FALSE );

GLfloat* pixels = new GLfloat[size * size];
//glReadPixels also returns 0s
//glReadPixels( 0, 0, size, size, GL_RED,  GL_FLOAT, pixels );
glGetTexImage( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, pixels );

pixelDataVector.resize( size * size );
for ( int i = 0; i < size * size; i++ )
{
  pixelDataVector[i] =  (float) pixels[i];
}
```

My shader code:

```
out float data;

void main()
{  
  data = 0.02;
}
```

This prints all 0s. And when I try GL_RGBA or GL_BRGA instead of GL_RED, I get (0, 0, 0, 1; ...).

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glGetTexImage`, as the name suggests, gets the pixel data from a *texture*. Specifically, the texture currently bound to the target you pass, in this case `GL_TEXTURE_2D`. And since the last thing you bound to `GL_TEXTURE_2D` was *zero*, it reads from the default texture.

If you want to [read pixels from the *framebuffer*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Buffer_reading), you must use `glReadPixels`. Though you must bind it to the `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`, and you must set `glReadBuffer` to point to the color buffer you want to read from.

But even if you did all that, you never actually *rendered* anything to the framebuffer.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, I have a similar question, what if I want to read from a FBO that has a 3D texture or a 2D texture array bound to it? Can I still use glReadPixels to read a particular layer? If no, then how can I do it?

Comment: @NicolBolas: any other reasons why it might fill the buffer with zeros? I'm dealing with a problem like this. On some hardware, it returns zeros.